# Thevenin equivalent with non-constant voltage

Tags: thevenin

Does Thevenin's Theorem cover the case where the voltage source is changing with time?  As an example of such a circuit, I'd like to replace a sensor, that produces a voltage, with a Thevenin equivalent in a model.  Presuming I have a model of the internal resistance of the sensor and a model of the voltage change with respect to stimulus change, am I allowed to say that **by Thevenin's Theorem** the equivalent circuit is a **variable** voltage source and a resistance in series?

Note that I am asking specifically if this is permitted under the theorem.  I know that I can model my sensor this way, I'm just not sure if I can invoke Thevenin as justification.

Comment: Sure, Thevenin's Theorem applies to AC and DC circuits.

Comment: An by AC we specifically do not mean just sinusoidal voltages, but any varying voltage?

Comment: Any varying voltage can be modeled by a summation of individual sine waves.

Comment: @Andyaka: any *continuously varying* voltage, perhaps, but not any arbitrary voltage variation.  However that is sufficient for my needs.  If you put it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky `any continuously varying voltage, perhaps, but not any arbitrary voltage variation` since when?

Comment: @Swedgin: continuous functions can only approximate other continuous functions.  Where there are discontinuities like jump discontinuities then there are many examples where you cannot approximate to arbitrary accuracy using continuous functions.  One of the most famous is the Gibb's Phenomenon, which happens when you try to use sinusoids to approximate a square wave: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GibbsPhenomenon.html  You literally can't.

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky Aah, though I still have yet to see a perfect square signal in my life. AFAIK discontinuous signal don't exist in the real world.

Comment: Agreed, however they do in a model of a circuit that is used for design.  However, luckily I don't need to go to that depth, since my sensor varies close enough to linearly over its range that I can approximate it as such, and a line over a finite interval does can be arbitrarily approximated by sinusoids.

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky The ringing involved in the Gibbs phenomenon doesn't go to zero magnitude as you add more terms, sure, but it *does* go to zero time. An infinite sum of sinusoids can indeed be exactly a square wave.

Comment: @Hearth: Interesting.  I think I'll need to review to better understand the implications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you put it as an answer I'll accept it

Thevenin's Theorem applies to AC and DC circuits.

Oh go on then I'll add some more stuff from [hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/acthev.html): -

[image]

Comment: LoL +1 from me.